# Parcel build command not working

Tags: javascript, parceljs

I am following the basic tutorial for [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) to bundle js, css and image files.

My file structure

```
  dist
  node_modules
  src
    - index.html
    - style.css
    - index.js
    - somemodule.js
```

When I run `parcel ./src/index.html` a server is started and the website is displayed correctly. According to the tutorial you can finalize the build using `parcel build index.js`. I expected to get this output:

```
  dist
    - style.css
    - index.js
    - index.html
```

But instead, after running `parcel build index.js` I get this output:

```
  dist
    - 4wyd98y98790.css
    - 948y59hslas8.js
```

What could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Parcel Bundler output directory is `dist` by default, but you can specify an output directory by setting option (`-d`).

e.g.`parcel build src/index.html -d build --public-url .` You will get the final static files in the build directory.

Comment: In my case, parcel doesn’t build the final project, regardless of the directory name

Comment: @Masonz
I follow their steps and OSX can't even find `parcel`

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial may say `parcel build index.js`, but you should run `parcel build ./src/index.html`. The entry point of your app is index.html.

Answer (score 3):

Since some commands seem to change over time, I'm going to share here the set up that worked for me up to date.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/index.html -p 3000 --open",
    "build:parcel": "parcel build ./src/index.html --public-url ./ --no-source-maps",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run build:parcel",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist/*"
  }
```

And I run the script using `npm run-script build`

My tree project was:

```
project
    |dist
      |OUTPUT FILES
    |src
      |OTHER INPUT FOLDERS
      |index.html
    package.json
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the parcel docs seem to cut a few corners just to keep the explanation as short as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove old build stuff like `dist` folder and build again. It should work.

But if it doen't then delete `dist` as well as `.parcel-cache` folder. Than build again. It should work.